# Selecionar registros entre duas datas com intervalos de minutos pré-estabelecidos

Tags: sql

Tenho uma tabela que armazena dados coletados em intervalos de 5 minutos. Gostaria de selecionar os registros entre uma data/hora inicial e data/hora final. Até aí consigo fazer. Só que gostaria de incluir um terceiro parâmetro na query que seria o intervalo de tempo entre coletas. Ex. Registros de 30-01-2018 00:00:00 até 30-01-2018 12:00:00 em intervalos de 10 minutos.

Comment: exemplo de dados ? exemplo de como quer a saída ? estrutura das tabelas ? utilize o SQLFiddle se possível

Comment: A tabela tem somente dois campos: datahora (datetime), tag (varchar(30).
time                                         tag
2016-04-01 00:01:03.580 PDT_1_T13@PV
2016-04-01 00:06:03.580 PDT_1_T13@PV
2016-04-01 00:11:03.580 PDT_1_T13@PV
2016-04-01 00:16:03.580 PDT_1_T13@PV
2016-04-01 00:21:03.580 PDT_1_T13@PV
2016-04-01 00:26:03.580 PDT_1_T13@PV
2016-04-01 00:31:03.580 PDT_1_T13@PV
2016-04-01 00:36:03.580 PDT_1_T13@PV

Comment: Qual é o gerenciador de banco de dados?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Insira a seguinte clausula no WHERE:

```
DATEPART(MINUTE,[CAMPO DATA]) % 10 < 5
```

Explicando o que esta sendo feito: estou isolando último dígito do minuto de seu campo datetime e verificando se ele está contido em {0,1,2,3,4}. 
Com isso acredito que retornará os valores esperados.
Exemplo (serão retornados os itens em negrito:

- **30/01/2018 08:00**
  30/01/2018 08:05
  **30/01/2018 08:11**
  30/01/2018 08:17
  **30/01/2018 08:23**
  30/01/2018 08:28
  **30/01/2018 08:33**
  30/01/2018 08:38

---

A tabela tem somente dois campos: 
datahora (datetime) tag (varchar(30)
 
Conteúdo tabela: 
datahora    tag 
2016-04-01 00:01:03.580 PDT_1_T13@PV 
2016-04-01 00:06:03.580 PDT_1_T13@PV 
2016-04-01 00:11:03.580 PDT_1_T13@PV 
2016-04-01 00:16:03.580 PDT_1_T13@PV 
2016-04-01 00:21:03.580 PDT_1_T13@PV 
Caso a seleção seja 01-04-2016 00:00:00 até 01-04-2016 00:35:00 
Intervalo de 10 minutos. 
Saída Esperada 
datahora    tag 
2016-04-01 00:01:03.580 PDT_1_T13@PV 
2016-04-01 00:11:03.580 PDT_1_T13@PV 
2016-04-01 00:21:03.580 PDT_1_T13@PV

Comment: A tabela tem somente dois campos: 
datahora (datetime)
tag (varchar(30)
Conteúdo tabela:
datahora                                 tag
2016-04-01 00:01:03.580 PDT_1_T13@PV
2016-04-01 00:06:03.580 PDT_1_T13@PV
2016-04-01 00:11:03.580 PDT_1_T13@PV
2016-04-01 00:16:03.580 PDT_1_T13@PV
2016-04-01 00:21:03.580 PDT_1_T13@PV

Caso a seleção seja 01-04-2016 00:00:00 até 01-04-2016 00:35:00
Intervalo de 10 minutos. Saída Esperada

datahora                                 tag
2016-04-01 00:01:03.580 PDT_1_T13@PV
2016-04-01 00:11:03.580 PDT_1_T13@PV
2016-04-01 00:21:03.580 PDT_1_T13@PV

Comment: @SergioPaiva não consegui entender seu comentário, acredito que seja melhor você editar a pergunta e colocar mais estruturado lá.
Chegou a testar com adicionando a cláusula que coloquei na resposta no where? deu certo?

Comment: Coloquei a resposta no item acima.

Comment: Não entendi se chegou a testar com o código que eu passei acima ou não, pois entendo que você teria o resultado esperado. Ou qual o problema que ocorreu.

Comment: Felipe, como no banco tenho registros nas seguintes horas (hh:mm) em: 00:01, 00:06, 00:11, 00:16 e 00:21. Se minha seleção for de 00:00 a 00:35 com intervalos de 10 minutos, os registros que deveriam retornar são: 00:01, 00:11, 00:21.

Comment: Pelos testes que fiz por aqui, adicionando no seu where " AND DATEPART(MINUTE,datahora) % 10 < 5 " traria exatamente o resultado que você espera.

Comment: Perfeito Felipe. Realmente funcionou! Estava enganado.